# Selecting most recent MySQL rows by MAX(time) WHERE time <= x

Tags: mysql, distinct, max

I am selecting the most recent entries of a MySQL table with:

```
SELECT MAX(time) as most_recent, userID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
```

My problem is, if I want to limit the maximum time with:

```
WHERE time <= nnn
```

The query does not work anymore. Is there a solution for with without a subquery?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with subquery :

```
select t.userID, max(t.time)
from
   (
     select userID, time
     from tableName
     where time <= nnn
   ) t
group by t.userID
```

or simply :

```
     select userID, max(time)
     from tableName
     where time <= nnn
     group by userID
```

Comment: Unfortunetely this doesn't work. It will return an empty result for `userIDs with a time > nnn`; I have multiple rows with the same userID and I want the latest row with the highest time, but <= nnn

Comment: Thank you. I know that it is possible with a subquery, but im asking if it is without

Comment: @user1797670 - why don't you simply use `where time <= nnn`

Comment: because this will not neccessarily give me the newest entry.

Comment: @user1797670 - check it, both queries in my answer return exactly the same result.

Comment: I checked it and this does definately not work. The subquery works fine. The second query works as long as I dont have the `WHERE time <= nnn`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Wrong/empty result ? Exception ?

Comment: Wrong result: It gives me a too old entry (the oldest one)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause like so:

```
SELECT MAX(time) as most_recent, userID
FROM TableName
GROUP BY userID
HAVING MAX(time) <= nnn
ORDER BY most_recent DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunetely this doesn't work. It will return an empty result for `userIDs with a time > nnn`; I have multiple rows with the same userID and I want the latest row with the highest time, but <= nnn