# Why is 'ORDER BY' needed to get correct result from MySQL join?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the following query:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.caseID, time
FROM tbl_test t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, MAX( TIME ) 
    FROM tbl_test
    WHERE TIME <=1353143351
    GROUP BY caseID 
    ORDER BY caseID DESC -- ERROR HERE!
) s
USING (ID)
```

It seems that I only get the correct result if I use the `ORDER BY` in the inner join. Why is that? I am using the ID for the join, so the order should take no effekt.
If I remove the order by, I get too old entries from the database.
ID is the primary key, the caseID is a kind of object with multiple entries with different timestamps.

Comment: Can you explain in words what you are trying to do?

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` the `ID` column in your subquery. MySQL permits what you're doing, but returns unpredictable results...

Comment: You are relying on MySQL's broken non standard and non guaranteed `group by` behaviour.

Comment: An `order by` in a derived table (aka "sub-query") does not make any sense (at least not without a limit). You should sort the overall result.

Comment: @Mike Brant: This is what I am tying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216762/selecting-most-recent-mysql-rows-by-maxtime-where-time-x

Comment: @Mike Brant: sorry, This question from me describes it better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689759/mysql-get-newest-entries-older-than-xxx-performance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query is ambiguous:

```
SELECT ID, MAX( TIME ) 
FROM tbl_test
WHERE TIME <=1353143351
GROUP BY caseID
```

It's ambiguous because it does not guarantee that it returns the ID of the row where the MAX(TIME) occurs.  It returns the MAX(TIME) for each distinct value of `caseID`, but the value of other columns (like ID) is chosen arbitrarily from members of the group.

In practice, MySQL chooses the row that it finds *first* in the group as it scans rows in storage order.

Example:

```
caseID  ID  time
  1     10  15:00
  1     12  18:00
  1     14  13:00
```

The max time is 18:00, which is the row with ID 12.  But the query will return ID 10, simply because it's the first one in the group.  If you were to reverse the order with ORDER BY, it would return ID 14.  Still not the row where the max time is found, but it's from the other end of the group of rows.

Your query works with `ORDER BY caseID DESC` because, by coincidence, your Time values increase with the increasing ID.

This sort of query is actually an error in standard SQL and most other brands of SQL database.  MySQL permits it, trusting that you know how to form an unambiguous query.

The fix is to use columns in the select-list *only* if they are unambiguous, that is, if they are in the GROUP BY clause, then each group is guaranteed to have only one distinct value:

```
SELECT caseID, MAX( TIME ) 
FROM tbl_test
WHERE TIME <=1353143351
GROUP BY caseID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.caseID, time
FROM tbl_test t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT caseID, MAX( TIME ) maxtime
    FROM tbl_test
    WHERE TIME <=1353143351
    GROUP BY caseID
) s
ON t.caseID = s.caseID and t.time = s.maxtime
```

Comment: I would add `ticks` around TIME, since it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: I wouldn't since it isn't! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing that issue because you are getting the MAX(TIME) per caseID, but since you are grouping by caseID and NOT ID, you are getting an arbitrary ID.  That happens because when you use an aggregate function, like MAX, you must, for **every non-grouped field in the select** specify how you want to aggregate it.  That means, if it's in the SELECT and NOT in the GROUP BY, you have to tell MySQL how to aggregate.  If you don't then you get a RANDOM row (well, not *random* per se, but it's not going to be in an order that you necessarily expect).

The reason ORDER BY is working for you, is that it kind of tricks the query optimizer into sorting the results before grouping, which just so happens to produce the result you want, but be warned, that will not always be the case.

What you want is the ID that has the MAX(TIME) given a caseID.  Which means your INNER join needs to connect by caseID (not ID) and time (which will give you 1 row per each 1 row in the outer table).

Barmar beat me to the actual query, but that's the way you want to go.